# Why is the print statement in the if statement not running?

Tags: python-2.7

I am writing this calculator in python and I wanted to know why the print statement in any of the if statements is not running. Here is the code:

```
firstnum = raw_input("What is your first number?")
type(firstnum)

op  = raw_input("What is your operation?")
type(op)

secondnum = raw_input("What is your second number?")
type(secondnum)


 def main():
    if op == "*":
       answer = firstnum * secondnum
       print(answer)

    if op == "/":
       answer = firstnum / secondnum
       print(answer)

    if op == "-":
        answer = firstnum - secondnum
        print(answer)
```

the output:
     it just exits the code without an error.

Comment: You need call main method

Comment: You defined a function called `main`. Did you call it?

Comment: do i call by just putting main() like in java?

Comment: Calling a function `main` when it depends on global variables set by user input seems like a poor choice for a function name. Why doesn't `main` gather the input that it needs? Global variables shouldn't be used without a reason. There really is no reason here.

Comment: Python doesn't require a main method - do you really need it here?

Answer (score 1):

There are actually several separate problems with the code:

1. The main function is not called at all. You don't need it here anyway, so I have removed it.
2. In some environments, the return value of `raw_input` may contain a carriage return character. Use `strip()` to remove any whitespace from the input.
3. `raw_input` returns strings. You cannot do calculations with strings. You need to convert the input to numbers first.

---

```
firstnum = float(raw_input("What is your first number?").strip())

op  = raw_input("What is your operation?").strip()

secondnum = float(raw_input("What is your second number?").strip())

if op == "*":
    answer = firstnum * secondnum
    print(answer)

if op == "/":
   answer = firstnum / secondnum
   print(answer)

if op == "-":
    answer = firstnum - secondnum
    print(answer)
```

Comment: Would it make more sense to use `if` or `elif`?

Comment: @Ritiek Using `elif` would certainly improve readability of the code for humans, but not change behaviour.